# Design in RecyclerView item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Good day, I have items in `RecyclerView` I would like to add a blue strip with circles, with different start and stop circles like there is in attachment.
The question is, what is the best way to implement that design ?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple approach is to create three icons that represent the start, regular and the final stop and that are sufficiently tall to cover the entire item height.

You can then create an item layout consisting of an image and a text view.

In the adapter of the recycler view, you then assign the appropriate icon and name of bus stop to the item view.